Physics behind why a liquid being poured sometimes splashes and other times not?
Ok som this might be hard to visualize, but when pouring something like a coke can into a cup. Depending on how much liquid you have left in the can and the angle of the pour, the stream becomes smooth and breaks the surface without splashing. However if I angle it too high or low the stream becomes choppy and once it reaches the surface it splashes.
This is just intuition but it probably depends on surface tension, gravity, mass or volume left in can and angle (volume of drink leaving through the hole).
If someone could explain or send me to a paper, youtube video or refrence to this already being calculated / modelled or explained I would be very greatful.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A picture (or video) is worth a thousand words.  Linking to a video or including some photos showing what you are asking about would help.

This article doesn't have suitable equations, but links to others that do. The short answer is a splash is noticeable at sufficiently high Reynolds & Weber numbers.
